# SQL Subquery Distinct Values with new index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below given script is not correct. 
I just want to take distinct values from Positions table with type column is null and make an indexed table. These value should be available through out the script, ie, i need to store it in a temporary table. I think situation is clear. Please correct the following script.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id, Symbol) AS [Index], * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Id, Symbol FROM Positions WHERE [Type] IS NULL) DistinctList 
    INTO #NullTypeEntries)
```

Comment: When asking for help with an SQL query, **always** describe what you are trying to do.  Please don't make us try to decipher your intent from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are trying to save results into a temporary table.  You can't do that in a subquery.  Try this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id, Symbol) AS [Index], *
INTO #NullTypeEntries
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id, Symbol
      FROM Positions
      WHERE [Type] IS NULL
     ) DistinctList
```

Or two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Symbol
INTO #NullTypeEntries
FROM Positions WHERE [Type] IS NULL

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id, Symbol) AS [Index], *
FROM #NullTypeEntries
```